# Express early termination with STL algorithms

Tags: c++, stl, std

I'm trying to rewrite some loops in my code as standard library functions. The following snippet seems to follow a general model for early termination and I'm wondering how to express that without explicit loops?

```
auto sum = 0;
for (const string& key : keys) {
    if (my_map.find(key) == my_map.end())
        return nullptr;

    sum += my_map[key];
}
return make_unique<int>(sum);
```

Comment: Unrelated: Save yourself some trouble and just return `sum`. Pointers to single `int`s aren't all that helpful, smart or otherwise. Usually the pointer is bigger and harder to move around than the `int`

Comment: @user4581301 that is not the question mate!

Comment: Unrelated: If you cache the result of `my_map.find(key)`, you can reuse it at `sum += my_map[key];` and save a look-up.

Comment: @user4581301 The reason I return a pointer is so that I can return the error condition as a nullptr, don't know if that's the idiomatic way.

Comment: You can use `std::optional` which is better than pointers because the intent is explicit.

Comment: I can't think of anything in algorithm that does what you want and doesn't look abusive. You can bash something into working, but that'll probably harm readability.

Comment: You could use for_each and throw an exception from a lambda, but the trend of forcing oneself to use standard algorithms everywhere is misguided. Your current loop is perfectly readable and will perform just as fast.

Comment: @user4581301 I think it's mostly because of the naming of the STL algorithms that it looks abusive, isn't it? If `find_if` were named `terminate_early_if` (which seems to capture that algorithm's essence just as well), then cigien's solution would look perfectly natural (though as Marc says there doesn't seem to be any value in choosing that form over an explicit loop)

Comment: Code is supposed to describe behaviour, not to be taken literally, so the goal should be to clearly express intent. Using a find function for a side effect does not express intent all that well. Given the choice between a loop that clearly describes the behaviour and a function that doesn't, I'm going to take the clear description unless profiling says I need the less-clear solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible approach: compute `sum` as the side-effect of an algorithm that terminates early. e.g.

```
int sum = 0;
auto f = std::find_if(keys.begin(), keys.end(), [&](string const &key) {
                      if (my_map.find(key) == my_map.end())
                          return true;
                      sum += my_map[key];
});

return f == keys.end() ? make_unique(sum) : nullptr;
```

Comment: I was thinking two passes.  `std::find_if`, followed by a `std::sum`, but this is nice for single-pass

Comment: Actually, rereading the sample code, that looks an awful lot like `std::set_disjoint` followed by a `std::sum`

Comment: @MooingDuck It's not obvious to me how `std::set_difference` expresses early termination, could you write that up as an answer?

Comment: It doesn't, but it expresses intent well. In a perfect world the compiler will see what you're up to when optimizing, but I think that's overestimating the compiler's ability to infer intent. For now at any rate.